# Можете объяснить суть этого кода?

Tags: sql, plsql

Создается процедура и объявляются переменные. Но я не могу понять что значить этот кусок кода? Точнее для чего нужен оператор `is`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure UpdateCourse
   ( name_in IN varchar2 )
 IS
   cnumber number;
```

Comment: Вместо IS можете смело использовать AS - в данном контексте они эквивалентны.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure UpdateCourse ( name_in IN varchar2 ) --объявление процедуры
  IS  -- служебное слово, говорящее что дальше будет идти тело процедуры
  cnumber number; -- объявление переменной внутри процедуры
```

То есть ключевое слово `is` служит для разделения частей.